# CSS - border adding a second thick white line in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, list, border

I have created a drop down menu using JQuery but when I test it in Chrome, the third and lower level menus show a thick white line (across the centre of the list item) in addition to the border which should be added. This does not happen in other browsers. It only occurs when I apply the `border-top` parameter to the list items. This must be some bug related to CSS in chrome because I cannot see what it is I might be doing wrong. I have Googled the issue and have not found anyone with the same problem.

Take a look:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAuhsoj/2uGFC/6/)

[Full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/sAuhsoj/2uGFC/6/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some kind of 'collision' is happening between

```
.nav ul ul li:first-child{
    border-top:solid 1px white;
```

and

```
.nav ul li{
    border-bottom:solid 1px #fff;
```

I came up with somewhat of a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/2uGFC/9/):

```
/* THIRD +  LEVEL LISTS */
.nav ul ul li{
    border:none;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
    border-left:none;
}
```

Add this at the top of your third tier.

It seems this is a bug in chrome, but I have searched through chromium and not found anything related to this. You should [report](http://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/?token=YeM2DjrUfW-xgITTsDFtaoo_XkA%3A1333455970180&role=&continue=http%3A//code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry.do%3Fcan%3D2%26q%3Dli%2520border%26colspec%3DID%2520Pri%2520Mstone%2520ReleaseBlock%2520Area%2520Feature%2520Status%2520Owner%2520Summary) it.

Comment: Your solution doesn't really work because it adds in two extra borders around each li and the big line still shows up beneath the third level but I appreciate your help and I will report the bug. I have discovered that the bug is related to the `border-radius` property. Disabling the border radius seems to fix this issue (and I think it looks better without the border radius anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I inspected your fullscreen example in chrome devtools, and I found the following line:

```
.nav ul li {
  background: #777;
  border-bottom: solid 1px white; <---- I think this is your problem
}
```

When I commented out the border-bottom, it looked good to me, and there was no giant white line.

Comment: How can I keep the bottom border then?

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav ul ul li:first-child {
   border-top:solid 1px white; <-- that line causes your problem I think.
   border-top-right-radius: 8px;
   border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}​
```

Comment: I think so too, but I cannot take it out without losing the top border. How can I keep the top border and get rid of that random line across the `<li>` element?